# Teste unitário de implementações de uma classe generica

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, genéricos

Suponha que temos a seguinte Interface:

```
public interface ICRUDService<T>
{
    T Create(T entity);            
}
```

Implementação Abstrata:

```
public abstract class CrudService<T> : ICRUDService<T>        
{         
    IRepository repositorio;      
    public EntityService(IRepository rep)
    {
        repositorio= rep;            
    }  

    public virtual T Create(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity ");
        }
        repositorio.Add(instance);           
        return entity;
    }                  
}
```

Para cada objeto do meu domínio (Ex: Pessoa, Carro, Animal) irá implementar um serviço:

```
  public class PessoaService :CrudService<Model.Pessoa>{
    IRepository repositorio;      
    public PessoaService (IRepository repo):base(repo)
    {
        repositorio= repo;
    }
    public void MetodoPersonalizadoServicoPessoa(){
         var oi = "oi";
    }         
   } 

  public class CarroService :CrudService<Model.Carro>{
    IRepository repositorio;      
    public CarroService (IRepository repo):base(repo)
    {
        repositorio= repo;
    }
    public void MetodoPersonalizadoServicoCarro(){
         var oi = "oi2";
    }         
   }
```

-Qual a melhor maneira de testar cada implementação de CrudService?

-Para cada implementação devo repetir o teste do método Create da classe abstrata?

-Existe alguma maneira de criar um teste Abstrato genérico que automaticamente testa o método Create em todas as classes que o implementarem?

Answer (score 3):

## Qual a melhor maneira de testar cada implementação de CrudService?

Criando um teste explícito para cada implementação.

Você pode testar os métodos virtuais da classe abstrata criando no código dos testes uma herança desta classe e testando esta classe herdada. É importante fazer isso para garantir que o métodos virtuais não sobrescritos por nenhuma implementação concreta também sejam testados.

## Para cada implementação devo repetir o teste do método Create da classe abstrata?

Deve repetir o teste apenas para as implementações concretas que sobrescreverem o método virtual da classe pai abstrata.

Não precisa repetir o teste quando o método virtual não for sobrescrito senão você estará testando o mesmo código duas vezes.

## Existe alguma maneira de criar um teste Abstrato genérico que automaticamente testa o método Create em todas as classes que o implementarem?

Se você se refere a usar alguma mágica tipo reflection para identificar todas as implementações concretas e sair testando... Não é boa idéia. Cada teste deve ser expressivo, indicando muito claramente o que está sendo testado e com que objetivo.

Se você usar reflection para identificar o que testar, pode chegar um tempo em que esta busca não encontrará nada e o teste continuará lá "sujando" sua suíte de testes e eventualmente causando confusão do tipo: os serviços CRUD parecem estar sendo testados e não estão.

## Herança e testes

Evite usar herança apenas para reutilização de código.

Observe, pela quantidade de dúvidas que o uso de herança levantou, que herança adiciona bastante complexidade e quebra a abstração (veja que você precisa saber se uma classe sobrescreve ou não um método da classe pai para saber como testá-la ou para evitar testes repetidos).

O uso de herança, no seu exemplo, não está trazendo nenhum benefício.

Comment: Como devo fazer reuso de código sem usar herança? Classes utilitárias?

Comment: @LeoCBS Exatamente. A forma mais simples de reutilização é encapsular o código em uma classe independente e consumir esta classe. No caso desta pergunta, `CrudService` poderia ser simplesmente uma classe utilitária em vez de ser uma classe pai. O consumo dela poderia ser mais ou menos assim: `CrudService.Create<TipoEntidade>(repo, entidade)`. Os nomes provavelmente estão errados - o create parece não estar criando nada, mas isso é outro assunto.

Comment: Em quais casos é recomendado utilizar herança?

Comment: @LeoCBS Daí é um assunto extenso. Meu procedimento padrão é não usar herança de classe. Eu evito usar especialmente quando o código trata de regas de negócio e sou menos rígido quando se trata de soluções acessórias simples e mais genéricas de tecnologia. Não sei se já tem alguma pergunta assim aqui no SO e nem sei se seria off topic, mas você pode dar uma pesquisada e fazer uma pergunta se for o caso.